# Why Groovy constants can be incremented?

Tags: debugging, groovy

In Groovy Console , `++(++(++(++1++)++)++)++` evaluates to `5` !
**Why** ?
I would expect an error that **literal constants can not be incremented** !

Pre-Increment gives the next Integer, while Post-Increment gives the same Integer, but I would expect both to throw errors when used with literal constants.

[[ I am running this on Windows 10 with Groovy 2.4.10 with Java 1.8.0_101 ]]

Answer (score 7):

Nice question, I'd love to see an authoritative answer.

I kept a tab open on this and still see nothing, so I investigated myself. If you have the patience to read that, below is the perspective of a simple Groovy user (yours truly), looking at this with the tools I have and incomplete knowledge (hopefully not too mistaken).

In short: **the language design & compiler implementation care more about the power & flexibility offered by transformations, and this apparently comes at the cost of relaxing the strictness.**

Groovy is very permissive by design, and sometimes that might be a bit too much.

- `if (condition) int foo=1` is rejected by `javac` with "Declaration is not allowed here", because it makes no sense to declare a variable there, there must be a mistake, better check the code, right? Naaah it's OK for Groovy.
- `private` fields and methods [are not private](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-1875).
- `final` is [applied inconsistently](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-1628). You can increment a `final int`. That will be fixed in 2.5 though, see below.

Difference treatment of `final` between Groovy 2.4 & 2.5:

```
$ ./groovy-2.4.11/bin/groovy -e "final j=0; println(++j)"
1
$ ./groovy-2.5.0-alpha-1/bin/groovy -e "final j=0; println(++j)"
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
script_from_command_line: 1: The variable [j] is declared final but is reassigned
. At [1:20]  @ line 1, column 20.
   final j=0; println(++j)
                      ^
1 error
```

But no, Groovy 2.5 still does not prevent from incrementing a constant:

```
$ ./groovy-2.4.11/bin/groovy -e "println(++1)"
2
$ ./groovy-2.5.0-alpha-1/bin/groovy -e "println(++1)"
2
```

So what's happening there with `++1`?

I think the first important thing is Groovy is not Java, and it does not transform to Java language. It compiles to bytecode. And here `++` is vastly different in Groovy & Java.

Groovy has [9 compilation phases](http://melix.github.io/s2gx-deepdive-groovy-compiler/#/compilation-phases) (see [org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilePhase](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/gapi/org/codehaus/groovy/control/CompilePhase.html)): initialization, parsing, conversion, semantic analysis, canonicalization, instruction selection, class generation, output, finalization.

We can explore them with GroovyConsole. Let's start it on this simple snippet:

```
def foo() {
    ++1
}
```

I see nothing in Compilation and Parsing phases, but at Conversion phase, we get something interesting:

```
public java.lang.Object foo() {
    ++(1)
}
```

The constant is surrounded by parentheses. Hmm. Interesting, notice we can do `++(2+2)` and get `5`. There is no variable to increment here... It seems `++` is just a shortcut for a method like `incrementThis(thing)`, which either increments the thing and returns it, or if the thing is a constant, it adds 1 to the thing and returns the result.

In my IDE if I ctrl-click on `++` it gets me to `org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.next(Number self)`:

```
/**
 * Increment a Number by one.
 *
 * @param self a Number
 * @return an incremented Number
 * @since 1.0
 */
public static Number next(Number self) {
    return NumberNumberPlus.plus(self, ONE);
}
```

If I track that down, it only ends up doing `self + ONE`, so I don't know where the alteration of `self` happens, and I think it's not so simple. I mean `++(x)` is not just a shortcut to `DefaultGroovyMethods.next(x)`, there is more to it.

So let's see what happens if I compile the following with `javac` and `groovyc` respectively:

```
//Wat.java:
public class Wat {
    public int foo() {
        int i=1;
        return ++i;
    }
}

//wat.groovy:
def foo() {
  ++1
}
```

Here is what I get (Java 1.8, Groovy 2.4, focusing on the relevant part):

```
// Java:
0: iconst_1                // load int value 1 onto stack
1: istore_1                // store int value into variable #1
2: iinc          1, 1      // increment local variable #1 by 1
5: iload_1                 // load int value from local variable #1
6: ireturn                 // return that integer value

// Groovy:
43: iconst_1               // load int value 1 onto stack
44: iconst_1               // load another int value 1 onto stack
45: iadd                   // add those 2 ints (result stored on stack in place of first int, stack is popped by 1)
46: invokestatic  #58      // Invoke method java/lang/Integer.valueOf(previous result)
49: areturn                // Return that new Integer result
```

So **for Groovy `++1` is equivalent to `Integer.valueOf(1+1)`** (and strictness simply takes a backseat).

But what about `def foo(i) { ++i }`? I compiled that, `i` is obviously an `Object`, but I don't understand the resulting bytecode, I still see no reference to `DefaultGroovyMethods.next` or `NumberNumberPlus.plus`. That's where I think this analysis falls short, and would love to see an authoritative answer.

Comment: +1 , lots of interesting Points in this answer ! I think the transformations are the culprits for loosing the strictness !

Comment: Yes, nicely put! That's my main point. Hmmm I might edit and add that... thanks (not a native English speaker, I suck at conciseness)